# Indexing strategy for a query involving three views, multiple columns and several JOINs

Tags: sql-server, index, optimization

### The scenario

I am having issues with a SELECT query on a view named `V3`, which takes ages (I had to cancel in SSMS, it timeouts in the application). `V3` combines two other views, `V1` and `V2`, to get a one-row result in the end (WHERE clause with idx value).

`V3` is defined the following way:

```
SELECT Live_DataIdx, DTLive1, DTLive2, DTLive3, DTLive4, DTDelivery, DTData2, DTLive5, DTData3, DTData4, Desc, Counter, DataFormat, DataType, Live_QueueIdx, Live_QueueGUID
FROM V1

UNION

SELECT History_DataIdx, DTLive1, DTLive2, DTLive3, DTLive4, DTDelivery, DTData2, DTLive5, DTData3, DTData4, Desc, Counter, DataFormat, DataType, live_QueueIdx, Live_QueueGUID
FROM V2
```

`V1` definition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Live_Data.Live_DataIdx,dbo.Live_Queue.DTLive1,dbo.Live_Queue.DTLive2, dbo.Live_Queue.DTLive3,dbo.Live_Queue.DTLive4, dbo.Live_Data.DTData1 AS DTDelivery,dbo.Live_Data.DTData2, dbo.Live_Queue.DTLive5,dbo.Live_Data.DTData3,dbo.Live_Data.DTData4, dbo.MsgType.Desc, dbo.Live_Data.Counter, dbo.Live_Queue.DataFormat, dbo.Live_Data.DataType, dbo.Live_Queue.Live_QueueIdx, dbo.Live_Queue.Live_QueueGUID
FROM dbo.Data 
INNER JOIN dbo.Live_Data ON dbo.Data.DataGUID = dbo.Live_Data.DataGUID 
INNER JOIN dbo.MsgType ON dbo.Live_Data.MsgTypeGUID = dbo.MsgType.MsgTypeGUID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Live_Queue ON dbo.Live_Data.Live_QueueGUID = dbo.Live_Queue.Live_QueueGUID
ORDER BY dbo.Live_Data.Live_DataIdx DESC
```

`V2` is declared as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.History_Data.History_DataIdx, dbo.History_Queue.DTLive1, dbo.History_Queue.DTLive2, dbo.History_Queue.DTLive3, 
                  dbo.History_Queue.DTLive4, dbo.History_Data.DTData1 AS DTDelivery, dbo.History_Data.DTData2, dbo.History_Queue.DTLive5, 
                  dbo.History_Data.DTData3, dbo.History_Data.DTData4, dbo.MsgType.Desc, dbo.History_Data.Counter, dbo.History_Queue.DataFormat, dbo.History_Data.DataType, 
                  dbo.History_Queue.History_QueueIdx AS live_QueueIdx, dbo.History_Queue.Live_QueueGUID
FROM dbo.Data 
INNER JOIN dbo.History_Data ON dbo.Data.DataGUID = dbo.History_Data.DataGUID 
INNER JOIN dbo.MsgType ON dbo.History_Data.MsgTypeGUID = dbo.MsgType.MsgTypeGUID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.History_Queue ON dbo.History_Data.Live_QueueGUID = dbo.History_Queue.Live_QueueGUID
ORDER BY dbo.History_Data.History_DataIdx DESC
```

I am calling view `V3` via Linq2SQL (but I did also try in SSMS) with the following query:

```
SELECT [Desc],Counter,DataType,DataFormat,DTLive1,DTData3,DTData4,
       DTDelivery,DTData2,DTLive2,DTLive3,DTLive5,DTLive4
FROM V3
WHERE Live_QueueIdx = 4325324
```

### Table definitions

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data](
[DataIdx] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[DataGUID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Data_DataGUID]  DEFAULT (newid()),
[ColDataX1] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColDataX2] [int] NOT NULL,
[ColDataX3] [int] NOT NULL,
[ColDataX4] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColDataX5] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[ColDataX6] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,    
[ColDataX7] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Data] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [DataGUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =   
 OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Live_Data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Live_Data](
[Live_DataIdx] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ColLiveDataX1] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL CONSTRAINT  
    [DF_Live_Data_Live_DataGUID]  DEFAULT (newid()),
[Live_QueueGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[DataGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[MsgTypeGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[ColLiveDataX2] [int] NOT NULL,
[ColLiveDataX3] [int] NOT NULL,
[ColLiveDataX4] [int] NOT NULL,
[DataType] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Live_Data_DataType]  DEFAULT 
        ((0)),
[ColLiveDataX5] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColLiveDataX6] [datetime] NULL,
[ColLiveDataX7] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[Counter] [int] NULL,
[DTData3] [datetime] NULL,
[DTData2] [datetime] NULL,
[ColLiveDataX8] [datetime] NULL,
[DTData4] [datetime] NULL,
[DTData1] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Live_Data] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Live_DataGUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = 
 OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

MsgType:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MsgType](
[ColMsgTypeX1] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MsgTypeGUID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL CONSTRAINT   
 [DF_MsgType_MsgTypeGUID]  DEFAULT (newid()),
[Desc] [varchar](255) NULL, 
[ColMsgTypeX2] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColMsgTypeX3] [int] NULL,
[ColMsgTypeX4] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[ColMsgTypeX5] [varchar](max) NULL,
[ColMsgTypeX6] [int] NULL,
[ColMsgTypeX7] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_MsgType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [MsgTypeGUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =  
 OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MsgType]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT    
   [FK_MsgType_Table1] FOREIGN KEY([Table1GUID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table1] ([Table1GUID])
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MsgType] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MsgType_Table1]
```

Live_Queue:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Live_Queue](
[Live_QueueIdx] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Live_QueueGUID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Live_Queue_Live_QueueGUID]  DEFAULT (newid()),
[DTLive3] [datetime] NULL,
[DTLive5] [datetime] NULL,
[DataFormat] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX1] [varchar](44) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX2] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX3] [int] NULL,
[DTLive2] [datetime] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX4] [datetime] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX5] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX6] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX7] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX8] [varchar](max) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX9] [varchar](55) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX10] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX11] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX12] [varchar](10) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX13] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX14] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX15] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX16] [datetime] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX17] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX18] [int] NULL,   
[ColLiveQueueX19] [geography] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX20] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX21] [varchar](30) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX22] [varchar](650) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX23] [varchar](300) NULL,
[DTLive1] [datetime] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX24] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX25] [varchar](255) NULL,  
[ColLiveQueueX26] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX27] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX28] [varchar](max) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX29] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX30] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX31] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX32] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX33] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX34] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX35] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX36] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX37] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX38] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX39] [int] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX40] [datetime] NULL,
[ColLiveQueueX41] [int] NULL,
[DTLive4] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [Live_Queue_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [Live_QueueGUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = 
 OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Note:

- The tables History_Data and History_Queue nearly equal to Live_Data and Live_Queue, except that some columns are set as foreign key.

### My request

Thus, I am asking for hints about creating some indices (if recommended: how should those be structed) or reconsiderations about the query. I don't think this use-case is of anything unique, so there has to be plans outside for this kind of a query. Another issue is that I am not able to do much experimentation with nonclustered indices, because indices on the history tables can't be created (runs endlessly). I know that the tables are very large, thus requires some space on disk, so NCIs would probably be needed, but I would need a strategy and idea how to actually create the indices on the critical tables.

Note:

- As far as I could analyse the problem, the queries on the history tables are a central issue. If I do a simple select on the specific columns with a where clause on the history tables, the result is only returned in about 2 minutes on History_Data, while and it took ~2 minutes on History_Queue, with my hard drive being very busy.

I did also look at the database size:

- CurrentSizeMB: ~ 2000
- FreeSpaceMB: ~ 400
- Log: ~ 1500/1500

### Considerations

These views are just overwhelming to start digging into the solution of the right index composition. I did already try some nonclustered indices, but I am not sure about it, because the query just don't stop (waiting for more than 10 minutes), my feeling is that there's some other problem. The NCIs also didn't have any effect. Many different factors need to be considered:

- Multiple columns are requested. Which column set might be responsible for the delay? Only one, many, all but one?
- Multiple joins do exist
- Where clause is used on an idx value

The problem lies within `V2` that contains the history data (~1.5 million entries in each history table), `V1` can be called in an instance. But because `V3` is an UNION of both, `V3` suffers from the slowmotion effect of `V2`. The idea behind the `V3` is to combine live and history data to get one specific entry with the selected idx value (here: 4325324) in the end.

The `V1` and `V2` views are nearly equal, the only difference is that `V2` is built with the history tables (`History_Data` and `History_Queue`) instead of the live tables (`Live_Data` and `Live_Queue`), while both have the same structure.

The select query runs like endlessly, I stopped after a period of more than 10 minutes.

**Execution plan**

The execution plan can be regarded at the following PasteThePlan URI: [Estimated Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJed9ndOE)

**Note**: I removed the nonclustered indices. I tried to add to start from the beginning again to get an idea how to begin systematically on this kind of slowmotion issues.

Any help is kindly appreciated, not only indexwise, but conceptually, too. Thank you.

Comment: How many records do you expect to get as a result?

Comment: The query above may return 500000-1500000 rows, although in the end, I do only need one row, specified by the idx value on V3 like SELECT A.Col1,B.Col1,C.Col1,A.Col2,B.Col2,A.Col3,B.Col3,C.Col3,A.Col4,A.Col5, D.Col1 FROM V3 WHERE idx = 4325324, with idx being a column of one of the tables of the query above.

Comment: Insert this condition (WHERE idx = 4325324) by adding V3 view into your query source (FROM section or CTE)

Comment: You mean, I should split the views to add the WHERE clause? V3 is defined this way: SELECT * FROM V1 UNION SELECT * FROM V2 and gets called as above (with the WHERE clause). Can this get optimized? But what about the indices? I once learned that each join column should have its on nonclustered index on that specific table with the other columns included. What would this mean for the WHERE clause, should I add another NCI on the idx column including all other columns of that specific table?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM V1 WHERE idx = 4325324 UNION SELECT * FROM V2 WHERE idx = 4325324`. I hope the server is smart enough to insert the condition into subqueries and execute as the condition is in view text. PS. There is no `idx` field in your view source text...

Comment: Adding Query 3 and the estimated execution plan could help (If you are not able to add  the actual). You can try adding it to [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). Other than that we need to know which column idx is, and what the actual query is that you need help with, the one on V3 posted in the comments or the one posted in the question. Please edit the question so it is clear. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have edited my question above.

Comment: I would recommend defining your `v3` view using the specific columns required from the `v1` and `v2` views. Using the potent `*` (asterisk) to select all column has the potential to break things should the views `v1` and `v2`change in the future.

Comment: Good catch, thanks for the note. Is anything still unclear in my question? I did another edit.

Comment: The distinct (by many, many columns) is destroying your performance most likely. Do you really need distinct? Do you also need an order by on the view? Try creating a function V3 that recieves your idx value and filters both views instead of doing a view that queries both with a `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks EzLo for your improvement considerations. I tried, and I did remove the distinct as well as the order by, and did query only V2 first (with the where clause on it), but the query still didn't finish after 10 minutes. So what is going on here? Might this be any other issue like stats, cache, performance? How to get a grasp on it? I even tried to only select one column, no improvement. When I go into edit view and run the query. I am watching live how the rows do increment. First, very fast up to the last count of rows, but then it continues with iterations by 200 and my hdd is heard.

Comment: @kvirk make sure that your history tables have an index *starting* with the column `DataGUID` for History_Data and `Live_QueueGUID` for History_Queue. I'd suggest editing the question and just reducing it to V2's query performance for now.

Comment: @EzLo: Thanks for your great help, it did put me on the right track to get it done (see answer).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your great suggestions!

Thanks to EzLo's index suggestion and the lack of anyone's concreate answers, I finally felt inspired to give it a try: Learning by doing.

Combining what I had learned in theory with the first overwhelming use-case of the complex view, I created the following two nonclustered indices:

NC_History_Data:

```
CREATE INDEX NC_History_Data 
ON History_Data (DataGUID, MsgTypeGUID, Live_QueueGUID) 
INCLUDE (History_DataIdx, DTData1, DTData2, DTData3, DTData4, Counter, DataType)
```

NC_History_Queue:

```
CREATE INDEX NC_History_Queue 
ON History_Queue (Live_QueueGUID, History_QueueIdx) 
INCLUDE (DTLive1, DTLive2, DTLive3, DTLive4, DTLive5, DataFormat)
```

Both NCIs represent a composite index on the join and where columns with the select columns having been included.
Et voilà, the view V3 does get called in 6s now (instead of infinity minutes), I did even try from the application, same effect.

So let's reconsider: I started with a question of a first overwhelming problem, having to extend my question with more and more data, until I finally felt the courage to just do it. Having got this instant query results felt like surreal, I started to query the history tables first and got to see that a nonclustered Index scan was chosen with my newly created index.

The estimated execution plan for the view V3 looks like this now:
[estimated execution plan with new indices](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ1Tvd7F4)

As seen, the new indices get used in the bottom-right corner.

Thanks again for all your suggestions, I nearly lost hope this will start working fast.

Comment: Glad you could make it work :)